# MongoDB driver for PHP not working

Tags: php, mongodb, driver

I have downloaded PHP driver for mongodb from  https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb

Then I have copied `php_mongodb.dll` in `xampp/php/ext` folder
and also added `extension=php_mongodb.dll` in `php.ini` file

But still mongodb extension in not loading, it is not showing in `phpinfo()`.

In the PHP error log file I find this PHP Warning:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongodb.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.\r\n in Unknown on line 0 [Wed Apr 19 11:09:54.445878 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2120:tid 268] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

Please help.

I am running windows 7 on 64 bit

Comment: restart Apache?

Comment: Did you install the Mongo database?

Comment: yes mongo database is installed

Comment: Extra information is added by using the [edit] button below the question and not by adding comments.